# Plotting seaborn heatmap from XYZ data saved as different sized numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, seaborn, data-visualization, data-science

I have three arrays from a certain experiment that looks like the following

X : array of shape 19 X 1

Y : array of shape 350 X 1

Z : array of shape 350 X 19

If I do the following:

```
sns.heatmap(Z,cmap='jet', cbar=True);
```

The map is correct but X and Y axis tick labels are not correct.

Any idea how I can include all three (X, Y, and Z) information in the heatmap?

Edit:

say,

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

X = np.arange(5,190,10, dtype= int)
Y = np.arange(450,800,1)
Z = np.random.rand(350,19)



sns.heatmap(Z)
```

This form does not consider X and Y values for plotting Z. I would want a way to plot the Z values at the corresponding X and Y values. As if, Z = f(X,Y).

Comment: Can you please add a minimum working example to reproduce the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Check the [doc](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html), you can pass the arguments `xticklabels` and `yticklabels`

Comment: I think you want matplotliblib's `pcolormesh` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly creating a seaborn heatmap will result in too many yticklabels as seaborn creates categorical ticks.

```
sns.heatmap(Z, xticklabels=X, yticklabels=Y, square=False)
```

[image: standard heatmap]

With matplotlib, you can create a heatmap as:

```py
plt.imshow(Z, extent=[X[0] - 5, X[-1] + 5, Y[0] - 0.5, Y[-1] + 0.5], 
           aspect='auto', cmap='magma', interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()
```

For Seaborn to create the desired heatmap, a dataframe needs to be created with X as the columns and Y as the index:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

X = np.arange(5, 190, 10, dtype=int)
Y = np.arange(450, 800, 1)
Z = np.random.rand(350, 19)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=Z, columns=X, index=Y)
sns.heatmap(df, square=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Note that for most applications, the 'jet' colormap is [strongly advised against](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/).